60 ohm resistor in 0805 package unavailable
I am unable to find a 60 ohm resistor in the 0805 (in) package on Mouser or DigiKey or Farnell. Is this an unusual part or am I just looking for it wrong?

60 Ω is not a standard value, so I'm not surprised. Why do you need such an unusual value?

Y117260R0000B9W is available to order on digikey as pr 2024/08/26 (not in stock though). 60 ohm, 0.1% 0805(in). Pricey, but existing

@Hearth It's a common value for CAN bus or RS485 termination, in case you use a so-called "split" termination.

62 will often be 'close enough' for most purposes, or 56. What are the requirements of your application? Or what's your application, if you are unsure about its requirements?

@Neil_UK AN 96116 recommends a minimum termination resistance of 118Ω (so 56Ω wouldn't be sufficient for a split termination setup). CiA 303-1 (CANopen) recommends 124Ω and above: https://i.sstatic.net/bvsk48Ur.png


or am I just looking for it wrong?

If your application can handle a tolerance of +1.7% (or +1Ω) then you can use 60.4 Ω 1% instead. Here's a list of 0805-case (including wide package) resistors within the range of 59.4-60.6Ω (60Ω ± 1%):
DigiKey Link

What you'll get is in [59.8 Ω, 61 Ω] range i.e. 60 Ω -0.4% / +1.7%.
Or you can just use 62 Ω anyway. It's  a standard value and quite common. See if your application can handle this.

Nitpick: if the application can handle a tolerance of 1.67%. Since 60.4 is already 0.4 ohm in the wrong direction and the 60.4ohm resistor may have an error of 1% in itself.

@Lundin good catch. Edited accordingly. Thanks.

Resistor value exists according to the E series of preferred numbers.
Have a look at the wikipedia page
60 is not part of them.
There is almost always a way to adapt your design to only use the available resistor values. You can also use combinations to obtain a specific value such as two 30 Ohm is series to get to an equivalent 60 Ohm.

The first thing is to know what tolerance you can tolerate. If within 5% is good enough, then a 1% 62Ω resistor will fill the bill (E24 series, which are all manufactured in 1% tolerance these days).
If you need 1% tolerance and only want to buy 1% resistors (so that 60.4Ω, the closest E96 series resistor) is too far off, you can put two 120Ω 1% resistors in parallel, or two 30Ω 1% resistors in series.
If you need 0.01% tolerance, two Susumu 120Ω 0.01% resistors in parallel would do the trick, and are in stock at Digikey, at a price commensurate with the performance and accuracy they offer.
For ~0.1% tolerance there are more options, such as a 60.4Ω 0.1% resistor in parallel with a 9.09k 1% resistor.
More useful than these options, here are a couple tools that anyone working with analog electronics will probably find useful:

The resistor series (read the comments above it). The series are available in many places, however the Logwell presentation is really pleasant and has outlived the original website. I'll only copy a bit of it, since you should go there. E24, E48 and E96 are the most useful.



For calculating resistors to get a particular value or ratio, there are a few options. This one is one of the better ones:


Note that it missed the 120Ω||120Ω option because 120Ω is not in the E96 series. It's probably the preferred parallel option of 1% resistors since it would only be one BOM line item. You can find it by switching to the E24 series, but it's not going to be able to find combinations of E24 and E96 resistors, nothing is perfect.

There are standard series of resistor values, known as E6, E12, E24, E48, E96 and E192. The series follow an approximately geometric series, with two or three digits depending on the series. For reasons which seem to be lost to history, the standard values have some slight discrepancies with what you get if you calculate an ideal geometric series and round it.
E6, E12 and E24 have two digits, with E6 being a subset of E12 which is a subset of of E24. E48, E96 and E192 have three digits with E48 being a subset of E96 which is a subset of E192.
In practice 1% and better resistors are typically available in both E24 and E96 values. E192 values are pretty esoteric.
So the question becomes how precisely do you need to meet your 60 ohm specification?
The closest value in E96 to 60 ohm is 60.4 ohm, an error of just under 0.7%. This of course comes on top of the error from the resistor tolerance. So a 1% 60.04 ohm resistor could potentially have an error up to just under 1.7% compared to the desired value.
So what if we need to do better than that? we have two options.
One option is to use two resistors in series or parallel. 30 ohms is a standard E24 value, as is 120 ohms. It's generally possible to solder two resistors on top of each other without two much difficulty to make a parallel combination.
The other option is to use a tighter tolerance for example if we use a 60.4 ohm 0.1% resistor that gives us an overall error of just under 0.8%.

As others have already mentioned;
No, 60 ohm resistors are not standard values so they would be very unusual parts.
Technically, a closest standard part is 60.4 ohms, which should be within tolerance, but as also many have said, depending on your exact usage and standards you must adhere to, there may be a mandated resistor value you need to use which may be smaller or larger than 60 ohms.
In most bus termination schemes, the cable impedance itself has tolerance, and in most cases, if you must allow for cable tolerance and adjust the termination for best possible signal integrity, you would in general round the resistor value a bit upwards, so the termination preferably higher than lower compared to cable impedance, to manage reflections.
So 62 ohms should be fine. 1% tolerance between resistors is also fine so the imbalance for split terminatio is not too much off when using split termination with a HF coupling / filter capacitor.
Usually 0805 resistors are rated for 1/8 watts, and according to TI appnote, generally 1/4 watt 5% resistors are OK, but they cannot handle short circuits.
